# Is there any other way to install Tensorflow on python 3.9.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

When I try to install tensorflow on python 3.9, I get following error:

> ```
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
> ```

I know that Tensorflow is supported only up to Python 3.8. **Is there any other way to install tensorflow in python 3.9.1 without installing an older version of python?**

Comment: AFAIK no, you'll have to downgrade to use the pip version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible now. This problem is an active trend in this [Tensorflow GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44485).

There are some issues with the dependencies for the underlying C++ code. So they expect to have it available for the v2.5. However, it will start as a nightly build, so if you are planning to develop some production-ready application, I recommend you download a lower Python version to avoid waiting for a long time
until they release a stable build.